# how to make a release removing some features in git flow

Tags: git, release, git-flow

My current git flow `develop` branch contains many features, I would like to make a release with just some of them, and remove some others, which will be released later.

Usually I would do:

```
 git flow release start 1.1.0
```

but this would branch from `develop` with all the features already merged.

How can I do that?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create release branch by removing functions from develop, revert merge commits.

Find merge commit which you doesn't need and get SHA1 value. Then

```
git checkout release
git revert -m 1 <<SHA1 value>>
```

See also [Remove a single merged branch from master branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27295961/git-remove-a-single-merged-branch-from-master-branch/27301128#27301128)