# How to 'undo' one git commit whilst keeping all others since

Tags: git

I have a git repo with many commits. Lets say that we have these commits from past to present:

1. small changes
2. big feature addition
3. small changes
4. small changes

Now we have determined that for business reasons the big feature should be removed, but I want to keep the changes made since.

How best can I do that?

Comment: I usually use "git rebase -i HEAD~4" for this, delete the line with the commit not wanted, and there you go.

Comment: Rich - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7099833/how-to-revert-a-merge-commit-thats-already-pushed-to-remote-branch

Answer (score 6):

`git-rebase` is overkill for that, and you lose history.

Use this instead:

```
$ git revert <hash of commit 2>
```

Your history will then show you had it committed a feature, then removed it later.

Comment: I tried this but it's actually a merge commit - the hash doesn't work, it asks for a numerical value, but I'm unsure what value…

Comment: @RichBradshaw when trying to revert a merge commit, you need to tell `git revert` based on which parent it needs to evaluate the patch. If you want to revert the merged in changes you will have to use `git revert -m 1 <hash of commit 2>`.

Comment: And in general I would suggest taking a look at the [documentation of `git revert`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert).

Answer (score 0):

Perform an interactive rebase:

```
$ 'git rebase -i HEAD~4'
```

then delete the one you don't want from the list.  See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13061212/1024740