# Git revert a specific merge commit

Tags: git, merge, revert, post-commit

I'm trying to figure out the best way to completely remove my merge commit from Master.

So far what has happened is I merged my feature branch into Master, and pushed out those changes.  Other Dev's have also merged in their feature branches to Master and now my changes are under their commits.

I need to pull out my merge from my feature branch as that is causing problems while also keeping everyone else's changes in Master.

Git revert  isn't working as it wants me to decide on a main line and I can't tell which main line I need to use.

Whats the best way for me to fix this besides merging in a hot fix?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to revert a merge commit that's already pushed to remote branch?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7099833/how-to-revert-a-merge-commit-thats-already-pushed-to-remote-branch)

Comment: "I can't tell which main line" - you want the one that isn't your commits. Do `git log -1 MERGE_SHA^1` and `git log -1 MERGE_SHA^2` to figure that part out