# Accidentally git merged -s ours

Tags: git, git-merge

I accidentally ran `git merge -s ours` instead of `git merge -X ours`. This has already been pushed and several other commits (and regular merges) happened since then. What can I do now to restore the changes discarded by `git merge -s ours`? I tried checking out that commit and rebasing back to my branch but nothing works since git is telling me that its already up to date.

Comment: Was this a fast-forward merge, or do you have a merge commit you can inspect?

Comment: I have a merge commit

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to revert a merge commit that's already pushed to remote branch?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7099833/how-to-revert-a-merge-commit-thats-already-pushed-to-remote-branch)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reverting the merge commit worked.

Answer (score 0):

So for history like this:

```
o Merge (-sours)
|\
| \
o  o
P1 P2
```

I would assume you need to checkout some branch at P2 and run `git rebase P1`. Are you sure it does not rebase the content of your merged branch? I believe it should work.