# Git - revert to branches after failed merge?

Tags: git, git-merge

I have two branches, the head of each is at the respective last commit. If I merge the two, and there are conflicts I can't resolve (I am new to Git), can I simply checkout the last commits before the merge and have another go at it or attempt another strategy?

Comment: Check those two posts http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2389361/undo-a-git-merge-that-hasnt-been-pushed-yet and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7099833/how-to-revert-a-merge-commit-thats-already-pushed-to-remote-branch. You should be able to find an answer.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me you simply want to abort the merge. The modern way to do this is:

```
git merge --abort
```

And the slightly older way:

```
git reset --merge
```

The old-school way would be (warning: will discard all your local changes):

```
git reset --hard
```

It's worth noticing that `git merge --abort` is only equivalent to `git reset --merge` given that `MERGE_HEAD` is present. This can be read in the git help for merge command.

```
git merge --abort is equivalent to git reset --merge when MERGE_HEAD is present.
```

After a failed merge, when there is no `MERGE_HEAD`, the failed merge can be undone with `git reset --merge` but not necessarily with `git merge --abort`. This is why i find `git reset --merge` to be much more useful in everyday work.

In your case, any of the alternatives will work as you don't have a failed merge but just an ongoing merge you want to abort.