# Undo a git merge that has just been pushed and redo the merge

Tags: git, merge

I had some local commits and there were changes made on master. So I did a:

```
 git pull // it automatically merged and had a conflict with one file only.
 subl <file> // Made the wrong fix and saved it
 git commit // It opened nano and I Typed "fixed merge" saved it 
 git push master origin
```

How do I go back to before the pull and redo the merge and push? Especially get back to right before the merge.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to revert a merge commit that's already pushed to remote branch?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7099833/how-to-revert-a-merge-commit-thats-already-pushed-to-remote-branch)

Comment: There are more detailed instructions on undoing merges here: [Undoing mergers](https://git-scm.com/blog/2010/03/02/undoing-merges.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can revert that merge with:

```
git revert -m 1 (Commit id of the merge commit)
```

More informations can be found in [Official GUIDE](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/howto/revert-a-faulty-merge.txt)

And you can do it in other way by using `git reflog <branch>` to find out where your branch was before the merge, and `git reset --hard <commit_id>` to restore the old revision (you will get back to this commit). Then just you can `push` it back.

Reflog will show you older states of the branch, so you can return it to any change set you like.

**Make sure you are in correct branch**

Comment: So after I do this and do a pull will I get the same conflict I got before? And I see that the push i made with the wrong merge is still on master ?

Comment: This leaves Git with the erroneous belief that the merged commits are still on the target branch.

Answer (score 0):

You can revert to the last commit:

```
git revert HEAD
```

It will revert your commit as a new commit