# I merged my branch to the wrong branch and pushed it. Is there a way for me to revert only the changes from that branch?

Tags: git

Yeah, sorry I'm a bit noob at git, but I merged my branch(branchA) to a different branch(branchB) and pushed it to remote. I'm supposed to merge it with branch C. Now I want to revert it and just undo all the changes made by branchA to branchB. Is there a way to do that? D:

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to revert a merge commit that's already pushed to remote branch?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7099833/how-to-revert-a-merge-commit-thats-already-pushed-to-remote-branch)

Answer (score 1):

You can `select the commit-hash`, you want to go back. Then by `hard reset` remove all the changes. Then do `force push`, it would replace `remote/branchB` with your `local/branchB`.

```
$ git checkout branchB
$ git log                           # copy the commit-hash you want to back

# go back to a specific commit of branchB
$ git reset --hard <commit-hash>
$ git push -f origin HEAD           # force push, replace remote/branchB by local/branchB
```