# How to undo the merging of my remote branch into master

Tags: git, branch, gitlab

I just start learning gitlab and git. 
I merged my personal work branch into the master by mistake. I want to undo this action, what should I do? Thank you so much.

Comment: Or, if it was pushed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7099833/how-to-revert-a-merge-commit-thats-already-pushed-to-remote-branch

Comment: See the duplicates (@DanCornilescu's comments, though stackoverflow will auto-delete the first one once this is closed as a duplicate). Note: it may help you to think about this as "merged my work branch into *my* master" (rather than *the* master): there's *your* `master`, and there's another Git repository, over on `origin`, that has *its own* `master`. Your `origin/master` is *your* Git's memory of where `master` was on `origin` the last time your Git checked with their Git.