# Undoing Git Merge done in Web Editor

Tags: git, github, merge

I merged and committed two branches on GitHub using the web editor (and not on my local machine). I want to undo this committed merge, but am not sure what to do since all answers on here refer to merges that were done locally before pushing.

Comment: cant you update your local base and then undo the last commit?

Comment: Yeah. How? (I'm totally new to this)

Comment: Have a read at this, would help. Also you can clone your git repo to a new folder to play around with these changes and keep one copy backed up in case you feel unsure.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7099833/how-to-revert-a-merge-commit-thats-already-pushed-to-remote-branch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a solution that can help you, and this is defenitely not the only one !

Pull on the branch you merged into :

```
git pull origin <yourbranch>
```

Reset your last commit :

```
git reset @^
```

And force push to your branch :

```
git push origin +<yourbranch>
(or)
git push origin <yourbranch> -f
```