# Git cherry pick creates duplicate commits

Tags: git, github, git-cherry-pick

After cherry-picking some commits from one branch to another branch, i still see commits when a pull request is created later.

Say for example, There is a git project which has two branches : Dev , Release.

And commit history is in following order.

DEV : a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6

RELEASE : a1, a2

Now if i cherry-picked commits a3 and a5 alone from Dev to Release. Now the commit history will be as shown below. cherry-picked commits will have new SHA (b1 & b2).

RELEASE : a1, a2, b1, b2.

Later if i try to create a pull request from Dev to Release branch, i stil see the commits a3 and a5.

But in this case how can i find difference in commits between these two branches?

I saw some articles stating 'rebase' but not able to understand the logic behind it.

Comment: That's exactly what `cherry-pick` is supposed to do: `Given one or more existing commits, apply the change each one introduces, recording a new commit for each. ` (from [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick#_description))

Answer (score 9):

Ideally, you rebase dev on top on the updated release first.

```
git checkout dev
git rebase release
```

The logic behind that is that Git should detect that a3 and a5 are the same as b1 and b2: meaning a3 and a5 won't be replayed at all.
The new dev branch (from which you will create a PR) won't have a3 and a5 anymore.

See also:

- "[`git merge` after `git cherry-pick`: avoiding duplicate commits](https://davitenio.wordpress.com/2008/09/27/git-merge-after-git-cherry-pick-avoiding-duplicate-commits/)"
- "[using `git rebase` to remove duplicate cherry-picked commits](http://www.kodama.gr/2013/07/28/using-git-rebase-to-remove-duplicate-cherry-picked-commits/)"