# How to revert a rebase - GIT

Tags: git, git-merge, git-reset

Here is my scenario.

I'm working with a team and I do not know who makes a mistake in the last merge/rebase. All I need is revert this commits completely and the issue is I do not know how many commits were involved.
It is too hard to ask which developer was the previous merge before the last one.

If there any ideas?
I completely lost the track in the develop branch, and the local is not updated.

Just to clarify I do not have the commit hash. It is not the same situation for this question.
[How to revert a merge commit that's already pushed to remote branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7099833/how-to-revert-a-merge-commit-thats-already-pushed-to-remote-branch)

Comment: git bisect is your friend.

Comment: One merge is one commit, and you should be able to see from the history who did any of the merges.

Comment: my example is not related with one commit sorry... a merge can be a lot of commits, for example a git-rebase

Comment: rebase != merge, one merge is one commit (i.e. the merge itself is *one commit* that merges one branch into another, and may have changes from many commits, but the merge itself is one single commit).

Comment: In other words: if your team is using rebase instead of merge, this is a very different thing than your question appears to be about and should be part of the question.

Comment: What about checking the reflog?