# how to undo git pull for the last commit when you dont have super rights of deleting the last commit

Tags: java, git

I have merged 2 feature branches using CLI. Now i find out they had to be merged the other way round, like not A to B, but B to A. i have also pushed the changes to central repo. Can anyone tell me if there is a way to revert these changes, undo a pull request and bring back the feature branch to last-1 commit stage, even for the central repo part?

Comment: You're going to have to revert both merge commits, push that, then redo the merges in the correct order.  If you hadn't already pushed to the remote, there would be a simple local fix you could have used.

Comment: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7099833/how-to-revert-a-merge-commit-thats-already-pushed-to-remote-branch) for how to do this.