# Git Undo Merge of Branches that was worked on at same time

Tags: git, github, merge, undo

We have a dev branch, and a separate feature branch which I've been working. Using GitHub's UI, I've accidentally merged the dev branch (and all it's new commits) into the feature branch.

I want to purge all of the dev branches changes. I thought about creating a new branch, then just cherry picking from the feature branch given the mess this has created.

Here is the Git log graph if that helps.

```
| *   14d6767 (origin/feature/) Merge branch 'development' into feature/
| |\
| |/
|/|
* |   2d88b27 Merge remote-tracking branch 'origin/master' into development
```

Comment: Has anyone pulled/synched the `feature` branch since the accidental merge?

Comment: Hi @TimBiegeleisen , yes people pulled the `feature` branch.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to revert a merge commit that's already pushed to remote branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7099833/how-to-revert-a-merge-commit-thats-already-pushed-to-remote-branch).

Comment: Please read the above link, which will explain how you may handle this.

Comment: I ended up force pushing the local version of my branch. Given that I had merged using GitHub's UI and hadn't pulled myself.

Comment: `and hadn't pulled myself` ... but is it possible that _others_ may have pulled?  This is why I asked that earlier question.  Of course, if you nuke the merge commit and force push, this is the easiest thing to do, but there is a risk there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could:

- `git reset commit_before_merge`
- `git checkout commit_before_merge` followed by `git checkout -b feature/this_works`, and then, optionally, cherry-pick in any other changes that look OK