# rollback to develop branch without last merge feature

Tags: git

I made a mistake merging my last feature with develop; I had just to finish my feature and then do a PR, and then merge trought github.

What is the right method to go back to before I merge my last feature  ?

[image]

I'm confused about when do 'git push', and really with a PR , I don't must use anymore git finish feature, not ? because this last merge, and I need to do PR to pass circle tests.

can I delete my remote branch (because i have a local with the same name)? before do push? that is better? in case of conflicts with the remote?

Comment: From GitHub, go to your PR and scroll down. There should be a "Revert" button. If you are working in collaboration with other users on the develop branch, it's the safer solution.

Comment: but i had no PR; that is the problem.. I merged it directly, so need rollback to do  a PR and not a finish feature that merge without pr

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7099833/how-to-revert-a-merge-commit-thats-already-pushed-to-remote-branch

Comment: thanks but? i use gitflow, so my branch is develop; i dont want to do mistakes with master

Comment: You should try and read through the answer. What you have to do is going in the develop branch and revert the commit. The revert will create a new commit that reverts all the changes. Now you have a clean deployment branch, and you can go back to your feature branch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are non-github solutions that can undo code changes from merge, which can be done in terminal(assuming you've checked out `develop` branch):

1. `git revert develop -m 2` and then `git push`.

   `git revert develop -m 2`: `git revert` means you're going to create a revert commit, and `develop` means your revert target is where your develop branch is pointing to, and `-m 2` means you're reverting a merge commit and you intend to revert change from second parent of merge.
2. `git reset develop^1 --hard`, and then `git reset origin/develop --mixed`, and then `git commit`(with messages like "Revert merge.")

   `git reset develop^1 --hard` means you're resetting `HEAD` & filesystem status to first parent of `develop`. So after this, your filesystem should not include changes from `develop` branch.

   `git reset origin/develop --mixed` means you're resetting `HEAD` into `origin/develop`, but preserve filesystem changes and add all into staged area. So after this, your filesystem should be exactly same to what it was before merge, and ready to commit.

Comment: thanks but too late, i do a git reset  --hard ae350e29e3d9aa194aa51f10befd677f0066f34f , and  git push origin $(git_current_branch) -f  , and now i've lost i think all the right develop branch, because ae350e29e3d9aa194aa51f10befd677f0066f34f it's a commit that i did not push ! git is really crazy

Comment: It’s because git doesn’t like removing changes. It’d much rather add additional commits which remove code.