# How to revert back a pull request in Stash?

Tags: git, github, bitbucket-server

I want to revert my pull request changes in master protected brach which accept changes only through pull request

I tried

```
git revert -m 1 commit code
git checkout -b rollback_branch
git add .
git commit -m 'rollback'
git push
```

When I opened a new pull request from `rollback` branch to master it says there are no changes in Diff tab.

Comment: Refer to the documentation for git revert, `Reverting a merge commit declares that you will never want the tree changes brought in by the merge. As a result, later merges will only bring in tree changes introduced by commits that are not ancestors of the previously reverted merge. This may or may not be what you want.` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7099833/how-to-revert-a-merge-commit-thats-already-pushed-to-remote-branch might give more context.

Comment: Did you specify the correct commit hash in your revert?  Did you specify the correct parent after -m?  Does your commit actually rollback the changes as expected?  A lot of possibilities for failure here.

Comment: Yes, the problem was I cann't see any difference between my branch and master when I create new PR from the reverted branch

Comment: If your master branch is configured on github to only accept changes through a pull request, and you have committed to it locally, you can't simply revert the changes as that will add an additional commit. Github will prevent pushes with new commits, regardless if the end result introduces changes or not.