# gitHub Desktop view Executed Command

Tags: github

Is it possible to view the commands executed by github desktop when I use it to commit, push, etc. ?

I am fairly knowledgeable about git, but pushing to github.com and a master by command line could use some work.
So, I am using GitHub desktop to commit back to github.com and would like to see the actual commands that the GitHub desktop app uses when I push the "publish repository" button... and others.

Github Desktop for Mac if it makes a difference.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Check first the logs, as seen in [`desktop/desktop` issue 7690](https://github.com/desktop/desktop/issues/7690#issuecomment-499608940)

> To access the log files go to the file menu in GitHub Desktop and select Help > Show Logs in Finder (macOS) or Explorer (Windows).
>
> The log files are created daily

[`desktop/desktop` issue 8516](https://github.com/desktop/desktop/issues/8516) made a similar request, but the answer was:

> This is an interesting idea, but but not something that we will likely tackle in the near-term. I'm going to label this issue as an enhancement and close it out -- if we get further feedback that this would be a valuable addition to GitHub Desktop it may be something we consider in the future.
>
> **If you are interested in viewing the specific actions that GitHub Desktop is performing you can open up the Developer Tools by going to the menu and selecting View > Toggle Developer Tools and selecting the Console tab.**
>   You will see the the specific Git commands that are being run, along with other output.
>
> For the most verbose output you can click the All levels dropdown and select Verbose.  The log files also provide a historical view of this data, and you can access those by going to Help > Show Logs.... If you have any specific questions about the commands that are being run let me know.