# Question about merge branch and good practices

Tags: git, github, merge, branch

My question could go into the basics of git but I have some misunderstanding and I wanted to have advice from the most experienced developers of git.

My scenario is as follows:

For some projet, I have two branch `preprod` and `master`

`preprod` : this branch is used to receive local developments from all developers, once the client validates these developments, I merge this `preprod` branch into `master`

`master` : is for the production environment.

**Scenario :**

I created a new branch to develop `auto-login` feature,

1. `git checkout preprod`
2. `git pull`
3. `git checkout -b auto_login_v1`

I developped this feature, I commited (2 files), pushed then I merged `auto_login_v1` branch into `preprod`. *Until here everything is good.

Now I create a new branch for another feature `newsletter`,

1. `git checkout preprod`
2. `git pull`
3. `git checkout -b newsletter_v1`

And like the first step, I commited (1 file), pushed then I merged `newsletter_v1` branch into `preprod`.

Now my client told me to deploy the newsletter feature in the production environment, so I merged `newsletter_v1` branch into `master`.

**The problem** with that is by merging just the 2nd branch `newsletter_v1` which contains (1 file basically), unintentionally, I also merged the (2 files) of the first branch `auto_login_v1` while I just wanted the second branch `newsletter_v1` with (1 file).

Why I got this (deployed 3 files instead of 1) ? because I merged the first branch in `preprod` then I pulled it ?

2) What is the recommended good practice in the case where we just want to merge one feature (branch) without another ?

Comment: To answer question 2: If you want to hold off on releasing all in-flight ready features, don't merge them into the branch that will go into prod just yet. You should read up on [git flow](https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/).

Comment: Ok @Lasse V. Karlsen, thank you

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen So if I understood correctly, we must merge the feature branches only into `develop` ? So in my scenario, I create a new branch `release` (intermediary between
develop and master), I merge develop into `release`, then in this `release`, I revert the merged branch that i didn't want in master `auto_login_v1` and finally, I merge the `release` into `master` and into 'develop' ? After that if I want to re-apply `auto_login_v1` because the client has just validated it, I create a new branch `auto_login_v2` with the same work as `auto_login_v1` and I merge it into develop ?

Answer (score 1):

`I developped this feature, I commited (2 files), pushed then I merged auto_login_v1 branch into preprod. *Until here everything is good.`

Well... I guess it all depends on what you call *good*. You are pushing code into develop that *might* not be finished and then when you start branches from it, you might have code from other features.... and then if you them merge this other feature (as you did on the second branch) into master, you are *for sure* carrying unfinished code... actually *unwanted* code because the client only requested a feature and you carried a lot more than that by merging develop.

So.... even if you push feature branches directly into develop (I don't agree with that workflow but, hey! If you like it like that, who am I to judge?), if you are asked to bring a single feature into master, you will *not* merge develop into master.... you *don't*  merge the feature branch into master... you bring over the revisions related to the feature **only** on top of master.

so... good practice:

there are countless workflows you can try but probably gitflow is the most popular... you might add stuff you like on top of it, but it is definitely a good starting point.

https://datasift.github.io/gitflow/IntroducingGitFlow.html

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

I followed the commits you described and took screenshots from a program called SourceTree to help visualize the branches.

[image: Git history as described by the asker]

Hopefully you can see that once you merge a branch into `preprod`, any branch checked out from `preprod` will necessarily inherit the merged changes.

In terms of best practices, a popular branching strategy is called GitFlow and it is similar to what you are already doing. GitFlow designates specific branches for specific purposes:

- `master`: reserved for version releases
- `develop`: reserved for merging feature branches (equivalent to your `preprod` branch)
- release branches: Before merging `develop` into `master`, you should checkout an intermediate "release" branch. The commit you branch from on `develop` does not have to be the head of `develop`.

Here's an in-depth article on GitFlow because there's more to it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/framework/devops/gitflow-branch-workflow

In the future you should not merge a feature branch into `develop` until you are sure you want to include it in the next release.

One way to "remove" the merged changes from `auto_login_v1` in `preprod` is `git revert`.

Take a look at [How to revert a merge commit that's already pushed to remote branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7099833/how-to-revert-a-merge-commit-thats-already-pushed-to-remote-branch/7100005#7100005) or look at the [git revert documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert)

Comment: Thank you for your time +1, I didn't understand the solution for only merging `newsletter_v1` without the other branch ?

Comment: `In the future you should not merge...` But develop is linked to the test environment that the client tests the features, is this case, if I understood correctly, we must merge the feature branches only into `develop` ? So in my scenario, I create a new branch `release` (intermediary between
develop and master), I merge develop into `release`, then in this `release`, I revert the merged feature that i didn't want `auto_login_v1` and finally, I merge the `release` into `master` and into 'develop' ?