# git revert of merge has no effect?

Tags: git, version-control

I'm using `git revert 028cf1f -m1 1` ([following this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7100005/6025788))

It yields the result:

```
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

I'm trying to undo this commit:

```
commit 028cf1f4969333a0e547a8ddbcd21d9647bb05c3
Merge: b1c0783 fa38861
```

The commit has already been pushed, if that's relevant to what I'm seeing.

Answer (score 1):

Nearly all git commands work on your local repo and don't touch the remote. This includes `reset` and `revert`.

Nothing changes on the remote until you `git push` them. If your local changes are [rewriting history](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History), then you need to force push them (`git push --force`), but you need to understand the [caveats and dangers of doing so](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61240088/8910547).