# Rollback to previous version in Gitlab

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I am new to Gitlab. We work on local branches in GIT and then push the changes before it get's merged to Master.

So I was trying to rollback a commit. But I somehow messed up and ended up bringing my colleagues commit's into my local branch.

Now I am trying to go back to previous version in Gitlab.
If you see the attached image, I am currently in the latest version but I want to go back to version 9. Is there anyway I can do this ?

[image: GitLab]

Comment: You need to _revert_ that unwanted merge commit.  [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7099833/how-to-revert-a-merge-commit-thats-already-pushed-to-remote-branch) for a general answer; not sure of the exact steps in GitLab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On GitLab Web UI itself, the revert operation is [documented here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/revert_changes.html#reverting-a-commit)

[image: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/img/cherry_pick_changes_commit.png]

The alternative would be to locally reset your branch to `HEAD~` and force push, which can work if you are the only one using this branch.
But reverting is safer, and only add a new commit (instead of overriding the recent branch history). That new commit will cancel the changes done in the commit you are reverting.