# Revert merged changes with git reset

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

I merged a pull request(will be referred as PR) in GIT accidentally. Now i want to undo the merge.

```
7b10185a28e09a74e395099435304852f0bb1a1d is the previous merge commit
5d8f83671ce03b1a3d181ec13e836833afa7b77c is the accidental merge commit
```

I checked out the branch that i merged the PR.

```
git checkout dev
git pull
git reset --hard 7b10185a28e09a74e395099435304852f0bb1a1d
git checkout -b my-new-branch
git push origin my-new-branch
```

and then try raising a PR to dev branch, i dont see any difference. Kindly help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: did you already push the change to dev on remote

Comment: The easiest way, _if_ nobody else has pulled the faulty commit yet, is `git checkout dev`, `git pull`, `git reset --hard 7b10185`, `git push --force origin dev`. That just gets rid of the merge commit entirely, instead of trying to revert it (which is tricky business, sadly, for reasons described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7101376/14637)).

Comment: Here is answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7099833/how-to-revert-a-merge-commit-thats-already-pushed-to-remote-branch

Answer (score 0):

When you run `git log`, you will see:

```
commit 23b86da331a5279efc541394d3adcbeb27aab3f1 (HEAD -> master)
Merge: d7cf911 ce96497
Author: Onur Demir <xx@x.com>
Date:   Wed Aug 26 13:54:47 2020 +0300

    Merge branch 'feature1'
```

Formula: `git revert <merge_commit_hash> -m <parent_number>`

Example:

You can run `git revert 23b86da331a5279efc541394d3adcbeb27aab3f1 -m 1`

Here `1` is referring to parent `d7cf911`, `2` is referring parent `ce96497`. Choose the one which you want to keep.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your suggestion Onur Demir, i was able to revert it.

git checkout dev

git checkout -b my-new-branch

git revert -m 1 5d8f83671ce03b1a3d181ec13e836833afa7b77c

git push origin my-new-branch

and raised PR, this helped.

But when i try to raise a PR once again from the branch that was merged accidentally, i don't see any difference :(