# Revert a merged pull request

Tags: ios, git, github, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

I’m working on a project where we have different branches ***(dev, feature,production)***. I was working on my `feature` branch, and did multiple **commits** on that branch for my changes. Later at some point I took a pull from `dev` branch and that got merged with my `feature` branch (which I shouldn’t have done). But, I didn’t realised that mistake at that time, and kept working on my `feature` branch, and did some more commits.

Now I want to only revert that pull taken from `dev` and keep all my commits of `feature` branch, also the one I did after the pull. Is it possible to save those commits? I know a little about ***Git Reset/revert*** command, but that will not save my later commits i guess. It will point `HEAD` to previous commit, before the pull.

Can anyone help how I can save my commits made after that merge? Or my understanding isn’t correct regarding ***Reset\Revert*** command?

**Note-:** Changes are already committed and pushed on remote.I’m using `Source Tree`.

Comment: Perhaps a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7099833/1256452)...

Comment: @torek 'git revert -m 1 <commit-hash>’ will revert to the tree of the first parent prior to the merge (In my case the feature). Will this command preserve the commits made after merge?

Comment: `git revert` does not revert *to* a commit. It *undoes* a commit: it's a sort of "reverse apply" the commit. Compare with `git cherry-pick`, which copies the changes found in a commit. When using `git revert` *on* a merge commit—which has two parents—Git has a problem: to copy or undo changes in a commit, Git needs to have *another commit to compare*. For ordinary (single-parent) commits, the other commit is *the* parent. Merge commits have *two* parents though, so there's no single "the" parent; `-m` tells revert and cherry-pick "which parent".

Comment: The result of a `git revert` is a *new commit*. All the existing commits remain. This is quite different from `git reset`, which allows you to take commits off of a branch.

Comment: Git's use of the English word *revert* here was a poor choice. Mercurial calls this operation `backout`, which is better. Both verbs are technically justifiable, but the English-language meaning of "revert" is more commonly the "revert to" meaning that is actually implemented with `git reset`.

Comment: Note, though, that I don't use SourceTree. If they have a button labeled `Reset|Revert`, that's weird labeling, because these are *very* different operations. Find someone who does know SourceTree before doing anything irreversible (or, perhaps simpler, make sure you use a fresh clone for all your experiments, leaving your *useful* clones untouched).

Comment: @torek Yes, I'm not using git for remotely as long as you are, but I already have had to explain this language trap to countless coworkers, since the confusion is more than commonplace. I sometimes wonder if they should have even created `git revert` as a command, rather than just giving a `--negative` option to `git cherry-pick`.

Answer (score 1):

1. In Sourcetree, double click the last commit before the merge.
   Doing so will make your working copy a 'detached HEAD' etc
2. Click "New Branch" and give it a name.
3. Navigate to all the commits you did after the merge, right-click them and choose "Cherry Pick"

Comment: Is there any way without creating a new branch?

Comment: I guess there is, but it's beyond my humble knowledge ‍♂️

Answer (score 0):

You just have to reset your checked out branch (with `git reset --hard`) to the point you want it to be. You may have to use `git reflog` if the point you desire has been  lost.

Until people don't realize, a bad usage of git can lead to developers losing their changes. It is convenient to backup changes using local mirrors sometimes.