# How to remove a feature from master-dev after has been intermingled with other feature commits?

Tags: git, git-reset, git-revert

Let's say we have a git repo with a master-dev branch.  When developers complete their features, each feature branch in merged into the master-dev.  One day, A large feature is merged into master-dev with several significant issues that are not discovered until a release branch is created.  To move forward, we need to remove this feature from the master-dev and recreate the release.  The issues in the feature are to be addressed after the release.  What is the strategy for removing this feature?

Edit

It this scenario, after the feature branch was merged and a few problems found, several updates were applied to the feature, which were then merged back into master before the decision was made to remove the feature from the release.  Those additional merges happened after other features were merged into the master-dev.

The branch history is too complicated for a simple revert command.

EDIT

If the community does not see this as a good question, I see no point in posting details about the solution that we found and used.

Comment: Revert the merge commit. See git-revert(1) and the `-m` option.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I revert a merge commit that has already been pushed to remote?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7099833/how-do-i-revert-a-merge-commit-that-has-already-been-pushed-to-remote)

Comment: Not really, I think that question was erased.  But thanks for the link, there are several other sub links that might hold good info.

Comment: RE Edit: multiple other things being merged after the feature is not a problem for git-revert(1) (modulo merge conflicts). git-revert(1) undoes the changes of the given commit.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, you would want to simply revert that commit from the branch and then create a new release.

On the command line, this would look like:

1. `git checkout master-dev`
2. `git log` - make note of the most recent commit sha
3. `git revert <sha>`
4. `git push`

At that point you can move forward with releasing and then you can bring that commit back into your main branch at a later time.

Comment: They want to revert a whole branch which has been merged in. That probably means reverting a merge and not a single commit.

Comment: True, depends on how it was merged in, whether it was squashed or not, could be multiple commits.

Comment: Would it matter if the problematic feature was merged in before several others?  Lets say there were about 4 other features that got merged in afterwards.  Also, the problematic feature involves more than one commit.

Comment: You can still revert a commit even after other commits have come into the branch. The only thing is you may have conflicts that would need to be resolved.

Comment: If reverting the commits is too messy, another option might be to reset the master-dev branch back to the commit sha right before the bad feature was merged. `git reset --hard sha`. Then you could force push to origin. Finally you could re-merge your good features, assuming those other branches were still in the repo. Make sure you make a copy of your main branch first so you don't lose anything.

Comment: Problem: I did something like that in the past.  Afterwards I think we had problems involving other dev branches that contained good code from master (via daily master merges) that was no longer found in the master after the reset.

Comment: Makes sense, yeah I think it's an option, but maybe the link @Guildenstern shared will work better for you if you're not sure you have the other features intact outside of the main branch.

Comment: What if we were to make the previous release the new master, and abandon the current master?  Is that a possible recommendation?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257277/discussion-between-david-lounsbrough-and-hoyt-jolly).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to revert a whole branch, first you would find the merge commit.

```
git log --oneline --graph --decorate
```

Then run

```
git checkout master-dev
git revert -m <parent-number> <merge-commit-hash>
git push origin master-dev
```

Answer (score -1):

- Abandon the current master-dev branch.
- Create a new branch from a commit with verified / tested code.

  - The last release is a good candidate.
- Make the new branch the new master-dev.
- Review the feature branches that need to be merged.

  - Thoroughly test each feature.
  - Remove any (old) master merge commits from each feature.

    - There should be no commits within the features that appear in the old master-dev, that don't also appear in the new master-dev.
- Merge the working features into the new master-dev.

Comment: This is effectively the _reset_ approach but with a new branch. Resetting to a previous commit and starting over, merging in the okay changes and leaving out the bad ones. See git-reset(1).

Comment: Except we get to keep the old master-dev branch intact.  I'm not sure how much that matters, but it does share history with many of the features (history that would be removed.)