# git undo commit on protected branch?

Tags: git, commit, git-commit

Is there a way to undo commits on a protected branch?

I mean, If you pushed an wrong commit, on a non protected branch you can undo it reseting the HEAD to the last desired commit or reverting the wrong commits and forcing the push then. But protected branches does not allow force pushing. What's the way to fix it on this case?

Edit: The specified (rigtht) commit is not a merge.

Comment: cant you reset the non protected branch to the commit you desire ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git: how to reverse-merge a commit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1809484/git-how-to-reverse-merge-a-commit)

Comment: Talk with the person who has admin rights on the protected branch. They are the one who accepted your pull request and will best know how they want it fixed.

Comment: @johnSmith Is a protected branch. I did another branch (a "restarotaion point") from the last right commit reseting the HEAD to the last right commit and creating a new branch. But I want to fix the protected branch if possible.

Comment: @msw Is not an option. The admins don't want/can change it.

Answer (score 19):

> reverting the wrong commit

```
git revert SHA-1    
git commit ....
git push origin <branch>
```

If your branch is protected, and you can't perform a `git push -f ...` then you can simply execute a `revert`.

> ***`git revert`***
> Revert some existing commits